# SQL - link to another table based on various rules?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have the below table which relates to sales and other dimensions.

```
SALEID  Shop    Channel   Value     Products     Opted In?  New/Repeat  
1        HOME    EMAIL    MEDIUM    CAR          OPTED IN   NEW          
2        GARDEN  PHONE    MEDIUM    INSURANCE    OPTED IN   REPEAT
```

I then have another table that looks like the below..

```
Shop      Channel   Value   Products        Opted in?     New/Repeat    RuleID         IsActive
All       Email     Medium  Car,Insurance   Opted In        All           888               1
Garden    Phone     Medium  Insurance       Opted In       Repeat         834               0
```

I need to link sales from the first table to pull the RuleID from the 2nd table where IsActive = 1. The link can only be made where all the values in the bottom table match the values in the top table

My issue is the way the data is stored on the 2nd table doesn't make it the easiest to link back. For example, some columns will have "All" in them... instead of the name of the SHOP. And also, the products column will sometimes have comma separated values in them instead of just one item.

In the example, the first table should pull through the ruleID 888 as it does match all of the criteria.. but what would be the best way to handle the columns that display either "ALL" or comma separated values?

I did find a split string function to handle comma separated values online, however I still can't get my head around how to implement it and deal with the "Alls"

Any ideas on how to handle this? I can't seem to find any similar issues when I search online!

Comment: Edit - so I found a way to handle the comma separated values by using this logic on the join..

 and ',' + a.products + ',' like '%,' + b.products+ ',%'

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, then you could just do it like this:

SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.[New/Repeat] = Table2.[New/Repeat]    OR Table2.ColumnName = 'ALL')

etc

Abstract example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb091e/5